# Creating Origin Destination Matrix from Station Locations

Tags: qgis, python, distance-matrix

I am attempting to create an origin destination matrix in python for all of the London Underground Stations. I have the station name and the lat, lng of its location. It is in the following csv format

```
Station Lat Lng
Abbey Road  51.53195199 0.003737786
Abbey Wood  51.49078408 0.120286371
Acton   51.51688696 -0.267675543
```

I wish to turn this list of stations into a matrix of all possible combinations of these stations. So, for the example above, I would like to achive:

```
O_Station   O_Lat   O_Lng   D_Station   D_Lat   D_Lng
Abbey Road  51.53195199 0.003737786 Abbey Road  51.53195199 0.003737786
Abbey Road  51.53195199 0.003737786 Abbey Wood  51.49078408 0.120286371
Abbey Road  51.53195199 0.003737786 Acton   51.51688696 -0.267675543
Abbey Wood  51.49078408 0.120286371 Abbey Road  51.53195199 0.003737786
Abbey Wood  51.49078408 0.120286371 Abbey Wood  51.49078408 0.120286371
Abbey Wood  51.49078408 0.120286371 Acton   51.51688696 -0.267675543
Acton   51.51688696 -0.267675543    Abbey Road  51.53195199 0.003737786
Acton   51.51688696 -0.267675543    Abbey Wood  51.49078408 0.120286371
Acton   51.51688696 -0.267675543    Acton   51.51688696 -0.267675543
```

Obviously, at this point I will need to cancel out the 0-0 combinations.

Comment: are you looking to get the Origin-Destination for above ground (on the streets) or below ground (as the subway travels)?

Comment: above ground. The intention is to then ask a directions shortest path API. So Im not actually using this for the analysis per se, rather this is how I am structuring the question I will ask of an external API